# Using copy-constructor in conjuction with std::make_shared

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, shared-ptr, copy-constructor, make-shared

I have defined a simple class `Integer` containing an `int` value, calling `std::make_shared<Integer>(&ref)` will force the program to use the constructor accepting an `int`. Did I implemented a wrong copy-constructor or there's something wrong with my using of `std::make_shared`?
What's the difference of calling `std::make_shared<Integer>(ref)`?
Also, why isn't `Integer copied_integer(integer);` make use of the copy-constructor? `Integer copied_integer(&integer);` is not allowed as well.

Here is the code

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include "DoubleLinkedList.h"

class Integer {
private:
    int number;
public:
    Integer(int number) : number(number) {}

    Integer(const Integer &integer) : number(integer.number) {}

    Integer& operator=(const Integer& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            number = other.number;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    int get() { return number; }

};

int main() {


    Integer integer(30);
    const Integer &ref = integer;
    Integer copied_integer(integer);
    auto pointer = std::make_shared<Integer>(&ref);
    auto sp = std::make_shared<Integer>(10);
    std::cout << "sp -> " << sp->get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pointer -> " << pointer->get() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&ref` is a `const Integer *`. It's certainly not compatible with the copy constructor. Did you mean to write `std::make_shared<Integer>(ref);` instead?

Comment: Side-note: You don't need to define a copy constructor or a copy assignment operator at all. C++ will make them for you (as well as move equivalent versions, which are not being generated for you because you explicitly defined copy constructor/assignment, though in this case it's mostly harmless since move semantics wouldn't gain you anything). Read up on [the Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) (and the Rule of Three/Five while you're at it); it's key to writing good C++ code. Rule of Zero would nearly halve your lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
auto pointer = std::make_shared<Integer>(&ref);
```

to this:

```
auto pointer = std::make_shared<Integer>(ref);
```

since you should have received an error similar to:

```
gcc-head/include/c++/10.0.0/ext/new_allocator.h:150:20: error: invalid conversion from 'const Integer*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
  150 |  noexcept(noexcept(::new((void *)__p)
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    |
      |                    const Integer*
  151 |        _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)))
      |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:8:17: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'Integer::Integer(int)'
    8 |     Integer(int number) : number(number) {}
      |             ~~~~^~~~~~
```

which informs/reminds you that `ref` is of type `const Integer*`, and you just need `const Integer&`, which is the type of the parameter in that copy constructor.